# Shortcuts for non-American Keyboard in Atom

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

I am using Atom on Ubuntu with a German keyboard.

I would like to use the shortcut to outdent code, this is done by **Ctrl + [**. For a German keybord, one has **[ = Alt Gr + 8** but **Ctrl + Alt Gr + 8** does not work.

On an American keyboard, the character **[** is positioned where the German keyboard has the letter **Ü**. But also **Ctrl + Ü** does not work.

How can I use the shortcut to outdent code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atom has some issues with International keyboards, the [keyboard-localization](https://atom.io/packages/keyboard-localization) package goes some way to improving the support for these keyboards.

You can install it from the GUI by going to `File` -> `Settings` selecting `Install` and search for `keyboard-localization`. You can also install it from the command line:

```
apm install keyboard-localization
```

Three German Language keyboards are supported:

- [German 105-key "QWERTZ"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_Germany.svg) (`de_DE`)
- [German Neo-Layout](http://www.neo-layout.org/) (`de_DE-neo`)
- [Swiss German](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/KB_Swiss.svg/450px-KB_Swiss.svg.png) (`de_CH`)

If these don't provide what you need then you can generate your own keymap:

[image: Screenshot of Keymap Generator]